# OpenCV line detection python

Tags: python, opencv

I have been trying to detect lines from 3D-printed rails.

The raw image looks something like this:

[image]

My problem is the following:

My OpenCV program detects two lines (for the upper edge and the lower edge of the rail).

[image]
This basically results in glitching of the drawn lane-line between both detected lines.

As I am new to OpenCV, I am not really sure what I can do to prevent that. I hope some of you can help me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Attach your code to your question for better understanding. And ask your question more clear. What exactly you want from output?

Comment: Probably you want to find contours instead of lines. Check out the [Python tutorials here](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/d05/tutorial_py_table_of_contents_contours.html) You will find ***many*** Questions/Answers for OpenCV that use findContours.

Comment: Try LineSegmentDetector or EDLines